# Database is not being created

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a database and perform some CRUD operations on said database.  Somehow when I try to insert and select, the following error occurs:

```
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testdb.MainActivity$Select cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at com.example.testdb.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-19 08:26:21.880: E/AndroidRuntime(2740):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I tried to create a seperate project to test out my code.  I have two simple buttons, one to insert the record, and another one to show the record retrieved in a `TextView`.  The insert works find, (I hope) however when I click on the button to retrieve the data the above error is shown and the app crashes.

The following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
static DatabaseImplementation di;
static SQLiteDatabase db;

Button btnInsert;
Button btnShow;
TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    di = new DatabaseImplementation(this);
    db = di.getWritableDatabase();

    btnInsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Insert().execute("");
        }
    });

    btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> result = new Select().execute("");
            txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            txtView.setText((CharSequence) result);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private static class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {       
            executeInsert();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private static String executeInsert()
{
    return "INSERT INTO tbl_Test VALUES(1, 'Testing');";
}

private static class Select extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String result = executeSelect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private static String executeSelect()
{
    return "SELECT test FROM tbl_Test WHERE _id = 1;";
}
```

}

And this is my .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnInsert"
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnInsert"
    android:text="Show"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnInsert"
    android:text=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm suspecting that the database is not being created, however if it is so, than the app would crash as soon as I hit the insert button. Any idea what the problem might be?

EDITED:

I'm sorry; I forgot to add the SQLIteOpenHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseImplementation extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private final String createTable = "CREATE TABLE tbl_Test (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT)";

public DatabaseImplementation(Context context) 
{
    super(context, "databaseName", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{


}
```

}

@sirackh
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498): java.lang.NullPointerException
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:43)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at com.example.testdb.MainActivity$Select.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:115)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at com.example.testdb.MainActivity$Select.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
     07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     07-19 09:32:05.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9498):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying the result on your TextView should be done on postExecute of your AsyncTask class. So implement this method and set the value there.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
     txtView.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity `  This is the error given as I entered the code that way

Comment: @ClaireG remove the static identifier from the AsyncTask class.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I am still however getting a NullPointerException at the onPostExecute()

Comment: Edited the main post, I'm very sorry but the code formatting is not working

Comment: executeSelect() is just a query string. To make an actual query you should go db.rawQuery(executeSelect(), null);

Comment: Yes, I figured that out so I put the actual statement in a `String` and passed it to the db.rawQuery(). The application doesn't crash now, but the problems keep arising.  When I click on btnShow, nothing is displayed in the TextView where it should display "Test".  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It gives error at this line:

```
txtView.setText((CharSequence) result);
```

Because it cannot automatically cast `AsyncTask` to `CharSequence`. It should be like this:

```
txtView.setText(result.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you sandrstar.  That fixed the error provided in the logcat however it still cannot work.